# how can I render this JSON use mustache.js without loop

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

here is the JSON:

```
   var data = [
            {
                "event": {
                    "name": "txt1",
                    "data": "2011-01-02",
                    "address": "Guangzhou Tianhe Mall"
                }
            },
            {
                "event": {
                    "name": "txt2",
                    "data": "2011-01-02",
                    "address": "Guangzhou Tianhe Mall"
                }
            },
            {
                "event": {
                    "name": "txt3",
                    "data": "2011-01-02",
                    "address": "Guangzhou Tianhe Mall"
                }
            }
        ];
```

and my mustache template is:

```
        {{#event}}
            <div>
                <h2>{{name}}</h2>
                <span>on {{data}}</span>
                <p>{{address}}</p>
            </div>
        {{/event}
```

so the template code above don not work.What I do now is make a `for` loop :

```
 var html = "";
 for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        html += Mustache.to_html(tmp, data[i]);
 }
```

Any better way to make it works without any loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is one way to do the same with just mustaches templates. you set your data as follows:

```
 var data = {data: [
    {
        "event": {
            "name": "txt1",
            "data": "2011-01-02",
            "address": "Guangzhou Tianhe Mall"
        }
    },
    {
        "event": {
            "name": "txt2",
            "data": "2011-01-02",
            "address": "Guangzhou Tianhe Mall"
        }
    },
    {
        "event": {
            "name": "txt3",
            "data": "2011-01-02",
            "address": "Guangzhou Tianhe Mall"
        }
    }
]};
```

and your template should look as follows:

```
{{data}}
{{#event}}
<div>
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
<span>on {{data}}</span>
<p>{{address}}</p>
</div>
{{/event}
{{/data}}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is the correct approach using mustache.js. As "user" shows, you need to have a name as a handle in order to itterate over the collection.