# How do I get Mustache to render this data

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I am new to the mustache template library and have the following scenario.  I am retrieving both a template and the data from a web server.  I am trying to combine the two using the following code:

```
function formatSearchResults(results)
{
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url:"search_result_template.mch",
        handleAs:"text",
        load: function(template)
        {
                //Load the template into a hidden div on the page
            var templateNode = dojo.byId("templateArea")
        templateNode.innerHTML = template;
    }
});

var templateNode = dojo.byId("templateArea");
var formattedResults;
formattedResults = Mustache.to_html(templateNode.innerHTML,results);
var templateNode = dojo.byId("outputArea");
outputArea.innerHTML = formattedResults;
}
```

Retrieving the json and the template work fine.  But the mustache never renders my data.

I have this json data:

```
{
      "data": [
            {
                  "ColumnValues": { 
                        "_0": "Bubbles", 
                        "_1": "Thompson%20Trucking",  
                        "_2": "A633937432DF91212431251256D350", 
                        "_3": "Eagleton", 
                        "_4": "CA", 
                        "_5": "555-555-5555", 
                        "_6": "12121", 
                        "_7": "Midatlantic", 
                        "_8": "Thompson%20Trucking..<snip>, 
                        "_9": ""
                  }
            }, <snip>
              ]
}
```

and this mustache template:

```
<table id="orgInfo">
    <tr>
        <th>Search results: <br/><br/></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Organization</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Region</td>
        <td>Industry</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    {{data}}
  {{#ColumnValues}}

<tr>
    <td>{{_0}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Region</td>
    <td>Industry</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  {{/ColumnValues}}
  {{/data}}
```

and this is the output I get:

```
{{/data}}
Search results: 

Organization    City    State   Phone   NAICS   Region  Industry    Description
                                    NAICS   Region  Industry`
```

I have been over the docs and examples for hours.  Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Kelvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  I now feel like a dope.  I was not converting the json text to an object before passing it to the mustache library.  All is well now.  I hope this helps someone else who makes the same goofy mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
{{data}}
```

into

```
{{#data}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've already tried this.  It did not work.  I've modeled my code after this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799038/how-can-i-render-this-json-use-mustache-js-without-loop